# Compose Ui Icon() crashing in release build

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am facing this release build crash.
it takes me to the Icon().
its working fine in debug build.

```
IconButton(onClick = { finish.invoke() }) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = LocalAppResources.current.backArrow),
                    tint = customTheme.headingColor,
                    contentDescription = "Back"
                )
            }
        }
```

**java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Conflicting default method implementations androidx.compose.ui.Modifier androidx.compose.ui.draw.DrawModifier.then(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier)**

Comment: What is LocalAppResources ?

Answer (score 0):

This exact thing happened to me and it turned out the be an R8/proguard issue. Once I added the following rules I no longer saw this crash:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class androidx.compose.foundation.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class androidx.compose.ui.** { *; }
```

I'm a little stumped, since documentation I've seen seems to indicate that we shouldn't have to handle the rules explicitly ourselves, but this was the only thing that worked for me once I moved from 1.1.1 to 1.2.+ and up.